# removing tags for a string with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following function which should remove tags from an input string.

example in:

```
'<strong>hello <em>my name <strong>is</strong> </em></strong>'
```

result:

```
'hello my name is'
```

Currently I have this code, but not sure how to make it work with recursion.

---

```
const clean= (str) => {
    const tags = ['<strong>', '</strong>', '<em>', '</em>', '<del>', '</del>']
    let strSanited = ''
    tags.forEach(tag => {
        if (str.includes(tag)) {
            strSanited = str.replace(tag, '')
        }else{
            // recursion here??
        }
    })
}

clean('<strong>hello <em>my name <strong>is</strong> </em></strong>')
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to make this recursive to begin with …?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use the `createElement` and `innerText`

```
var div = document.createElement( "div" );
div.innerHTML = '<strong>hello <em>my name is </em></strong>';
console.log(div.innerText); //hello my name is
```

**Demo**

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<strong>hello <em>my name is </em></strong>';
console.log(div.innerText); //hello my name is
```

Comment: This would return `hello <em>my name is </em>` I believe.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Nope *hello my name is*

Answer (score 3):

Also You can use regular expression to do so.

EX.

```
 yourstring.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

Reference:[Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

This way you need not to worry about other html tags, it will take care of all the html tags. Let know if it helps